# Clarification about an exercise for a map that maps the point $(r,\theta) \mapsto (r,\theta + \phi)$ for a fixed angle $\phi$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am trying to show that if $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ maps the point in polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ to $(r,\theta + \phi)$, then $T$ is a linear map **without using matrices.**

However, I am running into some problems when converting to rectangular. Notice that given

So define $T(r,\theta) = (r, \theta + \phi) = (r\cos(\theta + \phi),r\sin(\theta + \phi)$.

$T(r_1,\theta_1) = T(r_1\cos\theta_1,r_1\sin\theta_1)$ and $T(r_2,\theta_2) = T(r_2\cos\theta_2,r_2\sin\theta_2)$, we have that $T(r_1, \theta_1) + T(r_2,\theta_2) = (r_1\cos\theta_1\phi - r_1\sin \theta_1\sin\phi + r_2\cos\theta_2\cos\phi - r_2\sin\theta_2\sin \phi, \dots)$ (similarly for the $y$ coordinate.)

Note that this is, however, not really equal to $T(r_1 + r_2, \theta_1 + \theta_2) = ((r_1+r_2)(\cos (\theta_1 + \theta_2)\cos\phi - \sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2)\sin\phi, \dots)$ (similarly for the $y$ coordinate).

Does this imply that the exercise asks for $r_1 = r_2$? Or am I missing something else entirely? This exercise was in Apostol's volume 2 of Multivariable Calculus, and this exercise is before matrices are introduced so we are not supposed to use them to prove that this is a rotation matrix.

Comment: @Buraian So basically we should define $T(\theta) = (r,\theta + \phi)$?

Comment: I'm not sure of the definitions in your book, but in my experience, usually you have to talk about both the coordinates when talking about the map. There are some formal procedure to describe ripping out a coordinate from the pair (a,b) but I forgot what that is now.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to prove the wrong fact. If I understand correctly, you want to prove that $T$ is linear in the coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a vector space. In practice, you want that $T(r_1\cos\theta_1,r_1\sin\theta_1)+T(r_2\cos\theta_2,r_2\sin\theta_2)$ $=T(r_1\cos\theta_1+r_2\cos\theta_2,r_1\sin\theta_1+r_2\sin\theta_2)$,  and not to $T(r_1 + r_2, \theta_1 + \theta_2)$.

Comment: ^^ Yeah, linearity means adding the vectors in the input space and mapping the sum is equivalent to mapping individual of the sum vectors to the out put first and finding the sum of individual outputs. The way you've considered the addition in the input is wrong. Under the line "note that this is , however...,". Put more concisely , this assumption you've made: $(r_1, \theta_1) + (r_2 , \theta_2) = (r_2 + r_1, \theta_1 + \theta_2)$ is wrong

Comment: So do I define $T(\phi) = (r,\theta + \phi)$ for some fixed point $(r,\theta)$?

Comment: I believe what you've written already is correct because the domain is $\mathbb{R^2}$ so you input a pair of numbers into T

Comment: @Buraian Right, so that leaves me confused. How do I continue with the problem?

Comment: Additivity means $f(u) + f(v) = f(u+v)$, here $u=(r_1,\theta_1)$ $ v= (r_2 , \theta_2)$ , the issue is $u+v$ doesn't mean you add the individual components if that makes sense

Comment: @Buraian But if we convert to rectangular, then it should mean exactly that, or am I wrong?

Comment: The polar components doesn't add so simply.  $u$ in rectangular, I get $u=(r_1 \cos \theta_1, r_1 \sin \theta_1)$ , and , $v=(r_2 \cos \theta_2 , r_2 \sin \theta_2)$, adding:

$$ u+v= (r_1 \cos \theta_1 + r_2 \cos \theta_2, ...)$$

Comment: I do see what you mean, but I don't see what I can do to prove the original statement without using matrices.